# How to multiply responding indexes of two lists

Tags: python, list, algorithm

I have two lists:

```
firstList = [1,2]
secondList = [3,4]
```

My goal is to multiply matching indexes and add them, assuming that lists always have the same but not hard coded length.

The result:

1 * 3 + 2 * 4 = 11

I would like solution to **don't use existing functions**.

Comment: Have you tried something? Is it working partially?

Comment: What do you have tried? How does the `zip` sound to you.  Please explain what do you mean by existing functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use any prebuilt functions, you can do this:

```
def dot(firstList, secondList):
    summation = 0
    idx = 0
    for i in firstList:
        summation += i * secondList[idx]
        idx += 1
    return summation
```

If you're okay with range and len:

```
def dot(l1, l2):
    temp = [l1[i]*l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))]
    summation = 0
    for i in temp:
        summation += i
    return summation
```

If your okay with the sum function:

```
def dot(l1, l2):
    return  sum(l1[i]*l2[i] for i in range(len(l1)))
```

You can also for safety add a:

```
assert len(l1) == len(l2)
```

Comment: Wonder if `sum` and `range` `len` not being considered as existing functions?~. :-). This OP is very ambiguous to me...

Comment: I feel like they aren't since they are needed for many for loops, but I will adjust if he needs them manually done :)

Comment: Added solution using only for loop :)

Comment: Note you don't need to use brackets `[ ]` when using `sum`. In fact, it's often much more efficient **not** to use them. And one last alternative: `sum(x*y for x,y in zip(l1,l2))`

Comment: Good catch, updated

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible solution using a simple iteration and index values.
We are clearly assuming that lists are always of the same length:

```
firstList = [1,2]
secondList = [3,4]

result = 0
index = 0
for item in firstList:
    result += firstList[index] * secondList[index]
    index += 1


print(result)
```

**Output**
11

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is iterating over the `firstList` and doing the computation. Finally, sum the result. To do that, you can use the `sum` function, or easily using a simple loop.

```
# you can use `simpleLen` instead of `len`
multiplications = [i * secondList[i-1] for i in firstList if i <= len(secondList)]
# loop to sum elements of multiplications or only `sum(multiplications)`
result = 0
for j in multiplications:
    result += j

print(result)
```

However, if you are not happy with the `len` function, easily can be implemented as of following:

```
def simpleLen(input_list):
    count = 0
    for i in input_list:
        count += 1
    return count
```

Secondly, if you only desire the product of two lists, you can do it like the following:

```
# if suppose the length of arrays are the same
idx = 0
result = 0
lenght_of_arr = simpleLen(firstList)
while idx < lenght_of_arr:
    result += (firstList[idx] * secondList[idx])
    idx += 1
```

Comment: Question - what if the firstList has [5, 6].  This won't work!